# How to rewrite GIT history to track an entire directory with GIT-LFS

Tags: git-lfs, bfg-repo-cleaner

I tried a lot of commands but it does not work:

```
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --convert-to-git-lfs 'lib/**' --no-blob-protection
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --convert-to-git-lfs 'lib' --no-blob-protection
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --convert-to-git-lfs 'lib/*' --no-blob-protection 
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --convert-to-git-lfs '*/lib/*' --no-blob-protection
```

Is it supported by BFG repo cleaner? If so, what is the command?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this with [`git lfs migrate import --include 'lib/**'`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn). It creates the correct `.gitattributes` with that so git will handle your future clone, pull, checkout and commits operations well.

Comment: I think the answer is wrong (or outdated?). Isn't the command called `git lfs migrate import`?